# How to upgrade node js version on google cloud build

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

So I recently upgraded my app from Angular 7 to Angular 8 and I'm having issues with the node version of the cloud build VM as Angular 8 requires node version 10.9 or greater as shown below:

[image: error]

How can I upgrade the node version of the Google cloud VM so I won't get this error again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok, so after hours of Googling around it turns out Google cloud platform offers a registry of different npm cloud builders for use with Google cloud build.

I could have solved my issue by creating my own docker image but I wanted to avoid this in favour of the default cloud builders docker image. I changed my cloudbuild.yaml file to include the following builder 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0' instead of 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm' this then updated the node version to node 10.10.0 and just like magic Angular 8 can now be built by google cloud build!

Specific node versions from the cloud builders repository can be found here: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/cloud-builders/GLOBAL/npm

[image: cloudbuild.yaml file]

Comment: You, sir, are a gentlemen and a scholar. You saved ME hours of googling to figure this out.

Comment: where can we find these versions?

Comment: Indeed - seems unnecessarily hard to find/guess which versions to use.

Comment: Versions can be found here: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/cloud-builders/GLOBAL/npm?gcrImageListsize=30 as mentioned by staad below

Answer (score 12):

As suggested by their documentation you should instead using an official node image and specifying the npm entrypoint:

```
steps:
- name: node:10.15.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
```

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/npm/README.md

Answer (score 9):

Okay, after hours of trying to compile my new app and search on Google, there is no clear information on how to use the new version of Node.js within the Google app engine platform.

I gave myself the task of building my own file cloudbuild.yaml to be used on the Google cloud platform and this was my result, I hope it helps many who must have the same error:

```
steps:

# Install node packages
- name: node:10.16.3
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']

# Build productive files
- name: node:10.16.3
  entrypoint: npm
  args: [ 'run', 'build', '--prod' ]

# Deploy to google cloud app engine
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '--version=demo']
```

You can access the original file here in [GitHub](https://github.com/sj-social-media/webpage2019/blob/master/cloudbuild.yaml)

Comment: Thank you Joes, this answer helped me to solve my error.

Answer (score 1):

This link has all the current versions and their tags:

https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/cloud-builders/GLOBAL/npm

For example in `cloudbuild.yaml` I used

[image]

which uses the `current` tag.

Answer (score 1):

`gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm` is outdated as stated in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/npm/README.md

Replace

```
name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
```

with:

```
name: 'node'
entrypoint: 'npm'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to latest [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-nodejs):

> Cloud Build enables you to use any publicly available container image to execute your tasks. The public [`node` image from Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) comes preinstalled with npm and yarn tools

So that means we can use any Node.js tag from Docker Hub.

As for me, I changed `- name: node` to `- name: node:lts` in `cloudbuild.yaml` and this helped to fix `Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported` issue with Nest.js application build step.